# Predict segmented lm outside of package

Tags: r, lm, predict

I have an array of outputs from hundreds of segmented linear models (made using the segmented package in R). I want to be able to use these outputs on new data, using the predict function. To be clear, I do not have the segmented linear model objects in my workspace; I just saved and reimported the relevant outputs (e.g. the coefficients and breakpoints). For this reason I can't simply use the predict.segmented function from the segmented package.

Below is a toy example based on [this link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/predicting-from-segmented-regression-td904903.html) that seems promising, but does not match the output of the predict.segmented function.

```
library(segmented) 
set.seed(12) 

xx <- 1:100 
zz <- runif(100) 
yy <- 2 + 1.5*pmax(xx-35,0) - 1.5*pmax(xx-70,0) + 
               15*pmax(zz-0.5,0) + rnorm(100,0,2) 
dati <- data.frame(x=xx,y=yy,z=zz) 

out.lm<-lm(y~x,data=dati) 
o<-## S3 method for class 'lm': 
     segmented(out.lm,seg.Z=~x,psi=list(x=c(30,60)), 
           control=seg.control(display=FALSE)) 

# Note that coefficients with U in the name are differences in slopes, not slopes. 
# Compare:
slope(o)
coef(o)[2] + coef(o)[3]
coef(o)[2] + coef(o)[3] + coef(o)[4]

# prediction 
pred <- data.frame(x = 1:100) 
pred$dummy1 <- pmax(pred$x - o$psi[1,2], 0) 
pred$dummy2 <- pmax(pred$x - o$psi[2,2], 0) 
pred$dummy3 <- I(pred$x > o$psi[1,2]) * (coef(o)[2] + coef(o)[3])
pred$dummy4 <- I(pred$x > o$psi[2,2]) * (coef(o)[2] + coef(o)[3] + coef(o)[4]) 
names(pred)[-1]<- names(model.frame(o))[-c(1,2)] 

# compute the prediction, using standard predict function 
# computing confidence intervals further 
# suppose that the breakpoints are fixed 
pred <- data.frame(pred, predict(o, newdata= pred, 
                       interval="confidence")) 

# Try prediction using the predict.segment version to compare
test <- predict.segmented(o)
plot(pred$fit, test, ylim = c(0, 100))
abline(0,1, col = "red")
# At least one segment not being predicted correctly?
```

Can I use the base r predict() function (not the segmented.predict() function) with the coefficients and break points saved from segmented linear models?

**UPDATE**
I figured out that the code above has issues (don't use it). Through some reverse engineering of the segmented.predict() function, I produced the design matrix and use that to predict values instead of directly using the predict() function. I do not consider this a full answer of the original question yet because predict() can also produce confidence intervals for the prediction, and I have not yet implemented that--question still open for someone to add confidence intervals.

```
library(segmented)


## Define function for making matrix of dummy variables (this is based on code from predict.segmented())
dummy.matrix <- function(x.values, x_names, psi.est = TRUE, nameU, nameV, diffSlope, est.psi) {
  # This function creates a model matrix with dummy variables for a segmented lm with two breakpoints.
  # Inputs:
  # x.values: the x values of the segmented lm
  # x_names: the name of the column of x values
  # psi.est: this is legacy from the predict.segmented function, leave it set to 'TRUE'
  # obj: the segmented lm object
  # nameU: names (class character) of 3rd and 4th coef, which are "U1.x" "U2.x" for lm with two breaks. Example: names(c(obj$coef[3], obj$coef[4]))
  # nameV: names (class character) of 5th and 6th coef, which are "psi1.x" "psi2.x" for lm with two breaks. Example: names(c(obj$coef[5], obj$coef[6]))
  # diffSlope: the coefficients (class numeric) with the slope differences; called U1.x and U2.x for lm with two breaks. Example: c(o$coef[3], o$coef[4])
  # est.psi: the estimated break points (class numeric); these are the estimated breakpoints from segmented.lm. Example: c(obj$psi[1,2], obj$psi[2,2])
  #
  n <- length(x.values)
  k <- length(est.psi)
  PSI <- matrix(rep(est.psi, rep(n, k)), ncol = k)
  newZ <- matrix(x.values, nrow = n, ncol = k, byrow = FALSE)
  dummy1 <- pmax(newZ - PSI, 0)
  if (psi.est) {
    V <- ifelse(newZ > PSI, -1, 0)
    dummy2 <- if (k == 1) 
      V * diffSlope
    else V %*% diag(diffSlope)
    newd <- cbind(x.values, dummy1, dummy2)
    colnames(newd) <- c(x_names, nameU, nameV)
  } else {
    newd <- cbind(x.values, dummy1)
    colnames(newd) <- c(x_names, nameU)
  }
  # if (!x_names %in% names(coef(obj.seg))) 
  #   newd <- newd[, -1, drop = FALSE]
  return(newd)
}

## Test dummy matrix function----------------------------------------------
set.seed(12)
xx<-1:100
zz<-runif(100)
yy<-2+1.5*pmax(xx-35,0)-1.5*pmax(xx-70,0)+15*pmax(zz-.5,0)+rnorm(100,0,2)
dati<-data.frame(x=xx,y=yy,z=zz)
out.lm<-lm(y~x,data=dati)

#1 segmented variable, 2 breakpoints: you have to specify starting values (vector) for psi:
o<-segmented(out.lm,seg.Z=~x,psi=c(30,60),
             control=seg.control(display=FALSE))
slope(o)
plot.segmented(o)
summary(o)


# Test dummy matrix fn with the same dataset
newdata <- dati
nameU1 <- c("U1.x", "U2.x")
nameV1 <- c("psi1.x", "psi2.x")
diffSlope1 <- c(o$coef[3], o$coef[4])
est.psi1 <- c(o$psi[1,2], o$psi[2,2])

test <- dummy.matrix(x.values = newdata$x, x_names = "x", psi.est = TRUE, 
                     nameU = nameU1, nameV = nameV1, diffSlope = diffSlope1, est.psi = est.psi1)


# Predict response variable using matrix multiplication
col1 <- matrix(1, nrow = dim(test)[1])
test <- cbind(col1, test) # Now test is the same as model.matrix(o)
predY <- coef(o) %*% t(test)
plot(predY[1,])
lines(predict.segmented(o), col = "blue") # good, predict.segmented gives same answer
```

Comment: Why are you using a column named `xx` in your predict but it was called `x` in the original data.frame? For `predict()` to work, the names of the columns need to match exactly.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I fixed the column names in predict so that they match the original data.frame. The predicted fit now looks good for the first segment, but I'm still checking the other segments.

Comment: For anyone comparing with the Nabble link that inspired this code, I changed the definition of the slopes (because coefficients starting with 'U' are differences in slope according to the documentation).